# Formatting django form.non_field_errors in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I format django form.non_field_errors.as_text in a template without them being either an unordered list or having an `*` appended to the front?

`{{ form.non_field_errors.as_text }}` displays the errors with an `*` in front of the text.

This [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4471) was also helpful in explaining why the `*` will not be removed, but that doesn't help me.  I do not want the `*`.

Both {{ form.non_field_errors }} and {{ form.non_field_errors.as_ul }} display as an unordered list, and I do not want an unordered list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```

When you call the list of errors as text it will try to display it as a list. Simply loop through the list to get the error by itself so you can apply your own styling.

More info about it on the django project [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default Django forms use [ErrorList](https://github.com/django/django/blob/75d03c775553b9778db513213376d335d23819a8/django/forms/util.py#L48) as `error_class` ([proof link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/75d03c775553b9778db513213376d335d23819a8/django/forms/forms.py#L80)). As you can see, its `as_text` method formats list by prepending asterisks to values.

So, you can create some custom `error_class` with own `as_text` method and pass it to your form in a suitable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through `form.non_field_errors` is not always the best approach, for instance in my case I wanted to display a tooltip [like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7GY6.png) next to the field in question using [Django Widget Tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks).

**project/app/templates/template.html**

```
{% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" data-toggle="tooltip" title=field.errors.as_text %}
```

Instead of messing around with template code to pass the HTML `title` attribute in one piece I followed the tip from [@oblalex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642386/7192373) and wrote my own modified [`ErrorList` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/utils.py#L80) with a `as_text` method without asterisks.

**project/app/utils.py**

```
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList

class MyErrorList(ErrorList):
"""
Modified version of the original Django ErrorList class.

ErrorList.as_text() does not print asterisks anymore.
"""
    def as_text(self):
        return '\n'.join(self)
```

Now that the `as_text()` function is overwritten, you can pass your class `MyErrorList` as the `error_class` argument of your `Form` or `ModelForm` or like in my case some `ModelForm` formset:

**project/app/views.py**

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from .forms import InputForm
from .utils import MyErrorList

def yourView(request):
    InputFormSet = formset_factory(InputForm)
    formset = InputFormSet(error_class=MyErrorList)

    context = {'formset': formset}
    return  render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

[And now the tooltip looks like this without the asterisk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wQ3T.png)

Instead of passing the `error_class` every time you instantiate a form in your views, you can just add this one-liner to your form class (see this answer from [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138924/7192373)):

**project/app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .utils import MyErrorList

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, row, **kwargs):
        super(InputForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_class = MyErrorList
```